# How do Leptons arise from Lambda decay?

Tags: particle-physics, homework-and-exercises, interactions

I have a question for an assignment:

> Use your understanding of the quark model of hadrons and the boson model of the weak nuclear interaction to explain how leptons can arise from lambda decay, especially when there is an emission of a muon and a muon antineutrino.

I'm a bit lost as to how to answer this; I'm not looking for the full answer (it is for an assessed assignment so the work needs to be original) but if anyone has any pointers as to where I should be starting I would be very grateful!

Comment: The big hint here is *"Use [...] the boson model of the weak nuclear interaction"*. Ask yourself what is special about the weak interaction as compared to the strong interaction?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for both those comments, I think I've worked it out!

Answer (score 0):

$$\Lambda \to p + \pi$$
$$\pi \to \mu + \bar\nu_\mu $$
therefore,
$$\Lambda \to p + \mu + \bar\nu_\mu $$

Comment: Or the W- could just directly decay into a muon and a muon antineutrino.